# How to configure the URL of generated reports in e-mail subscription of Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have Reporting Services 2005 running on a machine that I can access only through Internet by typing http://[server ip]/Reports. This works fine, but my problem is:

1. Go to a report and click Subscriptions
2. Select Delivered by E-mail
3. Check "Include link"
4. Create a schedule

At the specified time, I do receive the e-mail but the link to the report comes in the format http://[host name]/reportserver[...]. Clicking this link does not work because my pc can't resolve hostname.

How can I configure this link for Internet access? I mean, I want the link to be http://[server ip]/reportserver[...].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the `RSReportServer.config` on the server file for URLRoot configuration setting. See the [2005 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) of the documentation. The SSRS config files were changed and merged in SSRS 2008, so use the docs for the right version.